# Is manipulating an "imaginary" element faster than an element currently in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, clone

Say I'm using jQuery to loop through and perform some manipulation on existing web page elements. There are multiple changes to be made, the number of elements in the set is at least somewhat large, and the element structure is somewhat complex.

Assuming I get all the elements into the same jQuery object, would it be faster to use jQuery's .clone (or .detach) method to create an "imaginary" copy to work on, remove the current elements, then re-insert the changed copy into the DOM?

...or does that not make a difference -- as live DOM elements manipulate just as fast as non-DOM ones?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/detach/ https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, actually, though your mileage may vary.

When an element is visible, manipulations will cause the browser to redraw the page. Many redraws can add up to a significant performance hit.

When an element is invisible, no redraws will be triggered.

Mass element clones are probably pretty costly, so I'd avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: But visibility does not depend on whether the element is already attached to the DOM or not. It also will not get re-drawn if it is hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone that object or create a new document fragment. Make changes on that new object and replace it in the DOM:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

Working on an object that is not part of the DOM will not trigger any paint/reflows.
If performance is an issue do not use jQuery, use plain old Javascript as both cloneNode and createDocumentFragment are well supported.